# The Address Element HTML5

Tags: html, frontend

How to use HTML 5 specific tag **address** correctly? With Semantic Markup.

This one

```
<address>
    New York<br>
    +7 (495) 204-27-22<br>

    Paris<br>
    +375 (29) 658-77-46<br>
    +375 (17) 292-91-23
</address>
```

or this one?

```
<address>
<p>
    New York<br>
    +7 (495) 204-27-22
</p>
<p>
    Paris<br>
    +375 (29) 658-77-46<br>
    +375 (17) 292-91-23
</p>
```

Comment: A very brief Google search for  `The address element HTML5` gives me resources like [this one.](http://html5doctor.com/the-address-element/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In html 4 only the first one is valid. In Html5 both are valid. I ran both examples through this validator http://validator.w3.org/check
You can just go there to check if you have something valid from now on but you will have to make a full document example like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd"><!-- <!DOCTYPE html> -->
<html>
<head>
<title> Test </title>
</head>
<body>
<address>
    New York<br>
    +7 (495) 204-27-22<br>

    Paris<br>
    +375 (29) 658-77-46<br>
    +375 (17) 292-91-23
</address>

<address>

<p>
    New York<br>
    +7 (495) 204-27-22
</p>
<p>
    Paris<br>
    +375 (29) 658-77-46<br>
    +375 (17) 292-91-23
</p>
</address>
</body>
</html>
```

The checker will give you easy to read errors you can fix.

Answer (score 0):

I always tend to use your first option.

```
<address>
 New York<br>
 +7 (495) 204-27-22<br>
 Paris<br>
 +375 (29) 658-77-46<br>
 +375 (17) 292-91-23
</address>
```